# iOS 9 Video Interstitial Ads crash

Tags: swift, video, ios9, ads, interstitial

There is an application with video interstitial ads which work perfect on all iOS versions except on iOS9 (iPhone 4s). On that device app crashes **before ad should appear**. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: any error logs?

Comment: can you not debug on simulator or device and see the error getting printed?